Congratulations on/for your successful performance?
In the sentence:
"Congratulations on/for your successful performance..."
What is the correct option "on" or "for"?

I think on is more appropriate. Using for seems to imply that the did the performance for you.  If that's the case, perhaps because you paid for it, then the second one would be better.
